# Средний показатель за выбранный период

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, morris.js

Есть таблица `online`, куда крон пишет данные каждые 5 минут.

```
| id | serverId | status | Players | date |
```

На странице есть вывод графика с помощью библиотеки *morris*. Данные `Players` вывожу за сутки запросом

```
$Onlinemodel->where('IdServer', $id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->findAll('288');
```

(288 записей за сутки, каждые 5 минут. Codeigniter 4). Получается загруженный график, но для суток пойдет.

Решил сделать аналогичный график за месяц, но с выводом среднего значения за сутки (в перспективе за год со среднемесячным значением).
Нашел более менее подходящий ответ,

```
SELECT AVG( Players ) FROM online WHERE  IdServer = 1 AND date BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND NOW( ) GROUP BY HOUR( date ) ORDER BY  id ASC
```

но не смог переделать его под свои нужды.

Comment: ``но не смог переделать его под свои нужды`` под какие? Вы можете объяснить что конкретно хотите сделать?

Comment: Я же написал под какие нужды. Подробнее: данные из таблицы разбивать на группы равные 1 час или 1 месяц и считать среднее арифметическое. Сейчас в базе данные онлайна каждые 5 минут и если вывести все данные в график за месяц, то это будет очень много.

Comment: и что это запрос не так делает, помимо того, что саму дату не выводит?

Comment: Ничего. Пустой результат.

Comment: Нужно взять данные за месяц, посчитать среднее арифметическое за каждый день месяца и в цикле вывести уже 30 значений. Я застопорился на этапе формирования правильного запроса к бд.

Comment: среднее за месяц по дням будет `SELECT DATE(\`date\`) AS d, avg(players) AS avg FROM online WHERE serverId = 1 AND \`date\` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW() GROUP BY DATE(\`date\`) ORDER BY d`